# Is $L\subset NC^1$

Tags: circuit-complexity, time-complexity

Arora and Barak's [online book](http://theory.cs.princeton.edu/complexity/book.pdf) claims in exercise 6.11 that $NC^1=L$. While the $NC^1\subset L$ direction is relatively straightforward and explained in many other texts, I couldn't prove or find the $L\subset NC^1$ direction anywhere. Since their book is just a draft, I was wondering if their claim was even true?

P.S. I apologize if this is not research-level. Just inform me in the comments and I will take it down if that is the case.

Comment: This is most certainly a typo for $\mathrm{NC^1\subseteq L}$. Anyway, $\mathrm{NC^1=L}$ is not known, and likely false.

Comment: It's corrected in the published book (where it is 6.14).